# Should I use a PopupWindow or DialogFragment for accepting input?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-popupwindow

I am doing a **Popup** with 3 Spinners and an EditText. After reading many blogs and articles I can't decide which is the best option, **PopupWindow** or **DialogFragment**.

The criteria would be:

1. **Compatibility** with different Android's versions
2. **Performance**

If there is a better way to do it I am open to change the perspective.

Thank you very much.

***DialogFragment:***

- Pros:
- Cons:

***PopupWindow:***

- Pros:
- Cons:

---

**EDIT: CONCLUSION**

**DialogFragment** allows you to use more complex features. Another important thing is that it is more tablet-friendly as it lets user to have opened more than one fragment at a time. Fragments are a more dynamic solution and they are the standard for newer Android versions.

**PopupWindow** is simpler and it is very helpful on simple questions to the user.

Comment: what decisions have gotten you to narrow it to one of these (do you know any pros or cons?). Also, consider posting a picture of what you want. These changes would make this an all-star post.

Comment: Thank you Phil, I'll try to improve the question!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The support library can give you a `DialogFragment` which is compatible with old versions of android. Go ahead with the fragment dialog cuz what you're asking is pretty specifical (3 spinners and an edittext. Just right click your project and press on "Android tools" --> "Add support library"
Make sure when you use the dialog to import

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Else you'll end up using the dialog without the support :P. You will have more flexibility with the dialog fragment and the power to use the view you see fit (even a layout made by yourself) without much effort.

Dialog Fragment

Pros:

- Capable of adding any view
- Easy to edit
- Can be adapted to tablets or cellphones in landscape or portrait just by modifying the layout
- Can dedicate a whole new class just to modify it your way

Cons:

- Cosumes more memory the more complex is your view
- Harder to code

Popup Window:

Pros:

- Simpler
- Easier to code
- It's more standard so it'll be harder for the user to be confused with it

Cons:

- Simpler, which means less control over it
- Limited to a few templates

These are just from the top of my mind and from my experience, but you should read the documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need EditText in your window and want to let your user to be able to longpress in it and paste (normal behaviour of an edit-text) then do not use popupwindow, I found it in hard way so:

A pretty Big **Cons** on popupwindow is that long press on edit-text wont bring default context menu (copy/paste/select all,...).also some reported in some devices this actually causes an app crash. see this 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62508