# Dialogs and Popups in Android

Tags: android, popup, popupwindow, dialogfragment

The Android design documentation in http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html makes a clear differentiation between Dialogs, Alerts, Popups and Toasts. It also recommends the implementation of **Dialogs** by means of the `DialogFragment` class and **Toasts** by means of the `Toast` class. However it's not clear to me whether **Popups** should be implemented with `PopupWindow` or with `DialogFragment`.

I know that `DialogFragments` usually come with Ok/Cancel buttons and that the location of `PopupWindows` can be defined, but:

- Are these slight differences the only arguments to use one or the other?
- Is `DialogFragment` the successor of `PopupWindow` that will be deprecated at some point?
- According to the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165554/2482894, PopupWindow is "Limited to a few templates", but I can't find any reference to a limited amount of templates in the class documentation.
- **So, finally, how would you implement Popups like these http://developer.android.com/design/media/dialogs_popups_example.png and why?**

Comment: Ok, according to [dialogs.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), they're recommending the use of `DialogFragment`even for windows such as [list_dialog](http://developer.android.com/images/ui/dialog_list.png) that doesn't have buttons. Besides, I guess that the fact of being based on `Fragments` eases it's addition to the BackStack, whereas I'm not clear how would I do that with a `PopupWindow`. Therefore, I'm going for the `DialogFragment` approach, although I would still appreciate some deeper details on the comparison of both classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want dialog as shown in the link, just make them by making custom dialog as mentioned below:

Make a dialog object:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

Set custom view to this dialog:

```
show_dialog(){
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);//your custom dialog layout.
}
```

Your custom layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_first_rl"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
<!-- write code for rest of your UI here -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now set alpha for your first relative layout in show_dialog() like this:

```
show_dialog(){
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);//your custom dialog layout.
    RelativeLayout custom_dialog_first_rl=(RelativeLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_first_rl);
        custom_dialog_first_rl.getBackground().setAlpha(170);
}
```

Call `show_dialog()` where you wanna show this dialog