# Fragment Back Press ,Loading back Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup

I have Fragment A which contains two button (Let say ButtonA and ButtonB), while pressing the ButtonB i am loading the fragment B (fragment B contains 1 Button, Let say Button C),while pressing button C ,the pop window is going to appear.

The problem I am facing now , when i back press then popwindow is disapperaing but loading Fragment A.

Actually I need when popwindow is showing in fragment B ,and user press back button then ,pop window should only disappear and it remain still in Fragment B ,not go to fragment A.

what i did , from the fragment B i had created one interface and pass the Popwindow instance in an Activity , and from the activity i am dismissing the popwindow.

```
 @Override
    public void onHandleRequest(PopupWindow popupWindow, PopupWindow backpopwindow, String fragmentName) {
        if(fragmentName !=null){
            this.fragmentName=fragmentName;
          if(popupWindow!=null){
              this.popupWindow=popupWindow;
              this.backpopwindow=backpopwindow;

          }
        }



@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        if(popupWindow!=null && popupWindow.isShowing()){
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            backpopwindow.dismiss();
        }
}
```

In My Fragment Class :

```
public interface OnHandleCallBack{
        public void onHandleRequest(PopupWindow popupWindow,PopupWindow backpopwindow,String fragmentName);
    }

public void showPopup(View view, Context context,ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

        if(popupWindow!=null && popupWindow.isShowing()){
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }

        mLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //Making transparent layout

        final View popupView1  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transparent_layout,
                (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.transprent));

        popupWindow1 = new PopupWindow(popupView1, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        popupWindow1.showAtLocation(popupView1, Gravity.CENTER, 0 , 0);
        popupWindow1.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindow1.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupWindow1.showAsDropDown(popupView1, 0, 0);

        final View popupView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_order_truck_popup_win,
                (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.popup_win));

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.truck_recyler_id);
        TextView textView=(TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.txt_truck);
        RelativeLayout cancl_rl=(RelativeLayout)popupView.findViewById(R.id.rl_cncl);
        textView.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.trucks));
        Config.colorFont(context,null,textView,null);
        popupView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.pop_up_window));

        /********* Here is my PopUp window ********/
        Float m=TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int m1=Math.round(m);
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,m1,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0 , 0);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        MyOrderPopUPAdapter mAdapter = new MyOrderPopUPAdapter(context, arrayList);
        LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        onHandleCallBack.onHandleRequest(popupWindow,popupWindow1,"orderfragment");

        popupWindow1.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                popupWindow1.dismiss();
                mLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(true);
                return true;
            }
        });



        cancl_rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                popupWindow1.dismiss();
                mLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(true);

            }
        });

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 0, 0);
    }

@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            onHandleCallBack = (OnHandleCallBack)context;

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement onHandleCallBack");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is popwindow extending from?

Comment: @masoudvali Popwindow is appear when i click button C in the Fragment B, programitically created like this PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: I know, I want to know its class is based on alertdialog or not

Comment: No , it's not based on the alertdialog , i want to know why fragment A is loading on the backpress

Comment: What if you remove `if(popupWindow!=null && popupWindow.isShowing()){
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            backpopwindow.dismiss();
        }` from `onBackPressed()` ?

Comment: From the fragment C when user press back button then , i had created the interface ,which is going to come to the Activity in the method onHandleRequest, in the onHandleRequest i am getting the popwindow instance , that instance i am passing to Activity onBackPressed

Comment: @MonishKamble if i dismiss the popwindow in onHandleRequest,then when we come to fragment B and press the ButtonC ,then popwindow will appear then suddenly disappear.

Comment: It would be better if you post more code.

Comment: @MonishKamble i had updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Unlike AlertDialogs, PopupWindows are not implicitly dismissed on back press. We have to explicitly write a logic for it.

Change your onBackPressed() as below :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(popupWindow!=null && popupWindow.isShowing()){
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            backpopwindow.dismiss();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
}
```

Here, we are first checking whether the PopupWindow is visible. And if it is visible, just dismiss the PopupWindow else allow the normal onBackPressed flow by calling `super.onBackPressed()`.

Don't know the exact reason of you using PopupWindow. Check this out for more options and decide what suits your need :

[Android Popup Window vs Android Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38735789/5460053)

[Dialogs and Popups in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18522362/5460053)

Comment: i think he is not having problem with popwindow , while back press , the fragment A is coming in visibility,He want fragment B when popwindow dismiss