# Android popup window for listview items

Tags: android, android-listview, popupwindow

I have a `ListView`, at the **bottom** of the screen, and each row is represented by an image, what I need here is to show a `PopupWindow`, at the ***`top center`*** part when I click on the row, kind of show some small details about it, I tried this

```
        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View view               = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.poi_popup_info, null);

                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(image);

            }
        });
```

but this shows it on the bottom left corner

thank you all for your time !

Comment: The popup will appear depending on the clicked view, if you want to relocate the view on the screen, check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450959/how-to-show-popupwindow-at-special-location

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a [DialogFragment instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165454/should-i-use-a-popupwindow-or-dialogfragment-for-accepting-input) and [customise its position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698410/position-of-dialogfragment-in-android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will need this, I ended up using this library, very useful

https://github.com/shardul/Android/tree/master/ChromeStyleHelpPopups

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PopUpWindow, give  ListPopupWindow a shot.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html

There are lots of hooks for positioning the pop up within/around a listview

Comment: "ListPopupWindow [...] *displays a list of choices*." This doesn't sound like what OP wanted.

Comment: yes, it can display choices.  Or it can simply be a popup with no choices.