# getLayoutParams().height returns -2 even after onGlobalLayout()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have an android dialog which i want to position in a specific position in its window.

I'm using API 8

how come `int a == -2` and `int b == 153` are not positive?

what is the difference between

```
getLayoutParams().height;
    mToolTipLayout.getHeight();
```

I have the following code

```
  public void initViews(int orientation) {

    mToolTipLayout = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tooltip_layout));

    ViewTreeObserver vto = mToolTipLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mToolTipLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        setPosition();
      }
    });


  private void setPosition() {
    int a = mToolTipLayout.getLayoutParams().height;
int b = mToolTipLayout.getHeight();

  }
```

Comment: why not use PopupWindow which can be placed anywhere in screen.

Comment: I would agree with using a PopupWindow for this behavior, but for calculation of a window, you should read the documentation. I believe its the onResume() in which the values for the LayoutParms actually get updated for the given view/window.

Comment: when to use PopupWindow and when dialog?

Comment: @Haresh when to use PopupWindow and when dialog ?

Comment: I think Dialog is by default shown screen center if you show such kind of popup/dialog at specific location then you prefer PopupWindow.

Comment: @JoxTraex   when to use PopupWindow and when dialog ?

Comment: A dialog should ONLY be used when you need the user to make a decision. If its just information being displayed then a PopupWindow should suffice.

Comment: @Haresh it says otherwise here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165454/should-i-use-a-popupwindow-or-dialogfragment-for-accepting-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout params specify how the measure and layout process should work. They are not updated in the measure/layout process. `-2` is the value for `WRAP_CONTENT`.

The measures themselves are available in the views themselves, not their layout params. `153` is the measured pixel height in your case, measured with `WRAP_CONTENT` spec.

Comment: but what will getLayoutParams().height return when in the xml layout_height= "3dp" ?

Comment: The requested height in pixels.

Comment: thanks. so in that case  `getLayoutParams().height;` and
    `mToolTipLayout.getHeight();` return the same?

Comment: Possibly but not necessarily - the measure process won't always give you exactly the specific size requested via layout params.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, -2 means WRAP_CONTENT. To get a height of a layout in this case you cannot use `getLayoutParams().height` or `getHeight()` (-2 and 0 respectively). You should get a height of inner view (for instance, with `view.getLayoutParams().height`). Probably add paddings.